# not able to download tomcat8 zip file via URL getting error Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: downloads.apache.org

Tags: java, tomcat, url, zip

im trying to download tomcat apache 7 zip from URL but getting error while doing the download.
but same method able to download other zip files via url.
code below:

```
FileOutputStream tomcat = new FileOutputStream(prop.getProperty("TOMCAT_FOLDER"));
tomcat.getChannel().transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(new URL("https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.108/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.108-windows-x64.zip").openStream()), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            log.info("Downloaded Successfully");
            tomcat.close();


error
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: downloads.apache.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
```

any help?

Comment: You should be using a [mirror site](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi). Also, why are you programmatically downloading tomcat 7?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i need to this way thats why.

Comment: @ElliottFrischi used the mirror site tomcat apache 7 but still getting above error have u tried doing this?

Comment: Just tried. Worked fine. Same code. Only I used `"https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.108/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.108-windows-x64.zip"`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i get this error Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu with that url above

Comment: Check your DNS settings. It's not your code. That works fine.